# Set status bar to light content and dynamically show/hide (UITabBarController with UINavigationControllers)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I have a UITabBarController as the root view controller. Each tab has a view controller embedded inside of a navigation controller. My navigation bars are a dark color so I need the status bar to be set to .lightContent. I also need to hide the status bar dynamically.

If I set "View controller-based status bar appearance" to "NO", I can set the status bar correctly to ".lightContent", but I cannot hide the status bar dynamically.

If I set "View controller-based status bar appearance" to "YES", the status bar will only set to ".lightContent" if a navigation bar is NOT present.

This is what I use in each view controller to show or hide the status bar:

```
var shouldHideStatusBar: Bool = false {
    didSet { self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate() }
}
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool { return shouldHideStatusBar }
override var preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation { return .slide }
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle { return .lightContent }
```

I have also tried:

navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black

There must be something I am missing in order to set the status bar to .lightContent and still be able to dynamically show and hide the status bar.

Answer (score 1):

Resulted to using a deprecated method:

```
UIApplication.shared.setStatusBarHidden(true, with: .slide)
```

Not ideal, but works. Hopefully, someone has a solution without relying on a deprecated method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bubble these values up through your view hierarchy. For instance, your `tabBarController` should be asking its `selectedViewController` what its value for `prefersStatusBarHidden` is then your `navigationController` needs to ask its `topViewController` what its value for `prefersStatusBarHidden` is. This way when `prefersStatusBarHidden` is called on the `tabBarController` it relays back what the top most view controller wants to do with the status bar.